# Cloudant support of https://user:secret@cloudant.com

Tags: couchdb, cloudant

I'm new to CouchDB but like [I read here](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/security.html), it looks like CouchDB supports:

```
http://user:secret@127.0.0.1:5984
```

But when trying this at Cloudant:

```
curl https://myuser:mysecret@cloudant.com/animalsdb/kangaroo
```

I keep getting html for a 404 - Page not found. Is this not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using the right host name. This should work:

```
curl https://myuser:mysecret@myuser.cloudant.com/animalsdb/kangaroo
```